# OLR for non-normal continuous dependent variable with two categorical independent variables?

Tags: regression, anova, nonparametric

| ID | Sex | Surface | B1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | female | UN | 1255 |
| 2 | female | UN | 542 |
| 3 | female | UN | 818 |
| 1 | female | UN | 274 |
| 2 | female | UN | 261 |
| 3 | female | UN | 314 |
| 1 | female | UP | 552 |
| 2 | female | UP | 548 |
| 3 | female | UP | 721 |
| 1 | female | UP | 431 |
| 2 | female | UP | 354 |
| 3 | female | UP | 738 |
| 4 | male | UN | 901 |
| 5 | male | UN | 619 |
| 6 | male | UN | 861 |
| 7 | male | UN | 713 |
| 8 | male | UN | 717 |
| 4 | male | UN | 275 |
| 5 | male | UN | 300 |
| 6 | male | UN | 244 |
| 7 | male | UN | 281 |
| 8 | male | UN | 231 |
| 4 | male | UP | 532 |
| 5 | male | UP | 451 |
| 6 | male | UP | 482 |
| 7 | male | UP | 374 |
| 8 | male | UP | 424 |
| 4 | male | UP | 193 |
| 5 | male | UP | 118 |
| 6 | male | UP | 207 |
| 7 | male | UP | 208 |
| 8 | male | UP | 252 |

I have a continuous dependent variable (B1) and two categorical independent variables:

1. Surface (with 2 levels: dorsal and ventral)
2. Sex (with 2 levels: male and female)

My DV is not normal. I want to understand the effect of both IVs on my DV along with their interaction.
If the data were normal, a two-way ANOVA would have solved the problem, but due to non-normality, this is proving difficult. I carried out a Ordinal regression after reading some posts but as there are k-1 intercepts, I am unable to understand the output. Is this the right way to proceed? If OLR is not appropriate how do I carry out a 'non-parametric' two-way ANOVA?

Comment: What is OLR?  What is ordinal regression? Perhaps you mean ordinal logit in both cases. Either way, marginal non-normality and even conditional non-normality would still allow a generalized linear model to be fitted  with an interaction term. Quite what would work best for you is impossible to say on this little information. Even "non-normal" could mean anything from a set-up that isn't really problematic for regression or ANOVA to one that is challenging for any method. Why not show us your data?

Comment: If your DV is continuous, ordinal logistic isn't going to work. 

ANOVA does not require a normal DV, it assumes normal errors.  If the residuals are very non-normal, you can try robust regression or quantile regression or other things.

Comment: @NickCox I have provided one subset of my data. However, there are multiple others like this. Overall, I am trying to understand how B1 varies across surfaces and between sexes.

Comment: @PeterFlom I did carry out an ANOVA as well, while the residuals were normal, variance was not homogeneous which is why I thought I would have to use a non-parametric equivalent. I will check the other two methods you have mentioned.

Comment: @PeterFlom ordinal semiparametric regression models work perfectly well on continuous DVs.  Ordinal regression has a major advantage here of being Y-transformation-invariant.  Resources are [here](https://fharrell.com/post/rpo) and a detailed case study with continuous Y is [here](https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/cony.html).  For example the proportional odds model generalizes the Wilcoxon and Kruskal-Wallis nonparametric methods.

Comment: @FrankHarrell's advice notwithstanding, applying a transformation (e.g. log) before regression or a generalized linear model with appropriate link is likely to be much closer to (1) what you will find in your literature (2) what supervisors or reviewers in your field understand best, (1) and (2) being essentially the same.

Comment: @NickCox thank you. And yes, in some cases log transforming helps but not all. In those cases does a glm with identity link seem appropriate?

Comment: @NickCox the log transformation is often not what it seems.  In many cases you have to use log(Y + c) and it is difficult to solve for c.  Analysts seem to take for granted that c=0 and this is often problematic.  In other cases, no value of c will satisfactorily do the job.  That's why I prefer methods that provide the same parameter estimates an standard errors no matter how Y is transformed (as long as the transformation is monotonic).  Ordinal methods are also robust to "outliers".

Comment: Indeed, @FrankHarrell, I am familiar with your preferences and arguments, but I don't see your approach as being simple to apply or understand for questions like this. I don't think one often needs to play with an extra constant; for measurements that can complicate and confuse more often as it seems to work. it's enough that working on log scale improves the analysis and is consistent often with biological ideas. The OP's data example seems fairly standard for biological data, with a slightly skewed outcome.

Comment: Generalized linear models with identity link could be a good idea but in that case a distribution like the gamma would possibly make more sense for a skewed outcome. It's also true that we can make no promises about data we can't see. The question started with your having one outcome and two predictors but is already morphing into your wanting several analyses which differ in ways you don't explain.

Comment: It is more of a general idea in understanding how to deal with data when assumptions for normality are not held through the specific example I provided. The question is still the same where I want to study one outcome with the two mentioned predictors. Im not sure what the several analyses are that you are referring to actually, and would be happy to clarify any specifics.

Comment: We'll have to have a friendly disagreement about this Nick.  Software makes continuous ordinal analysis easy, and you can get all kinds of interesting estimates from the fit, e.g., mean, quantiles, exceedance probabilities.  And you may be surprised how sensitive a log analysis to the choice of the centering constant $c$.  When $Y$ can be $\leq 0$ you **must** choose a $c$ and in other cases with an origin that much to the right of zero you need to use a negative $c$ to make things work well enough.  Example: frequency of premature ventricular contractions/h had 24 subtracted before logging.

Comment: @Frank Harrell Glad to disagree in friendly fashion. I am not surprised at sensitivity of results to choice of $c$ in $\log (y + c)$ and have made precisely the same point several times in technical forums. In particular, it's a dangerous misconception that choosing $c$ to be a very small positive number is a gentle fudge, which it is not. When $y$ can be negative then $\text{sign}(y) \log (1 + |y|)$ sometimes works but the choice $c = 1$ must indeed be checked. On the main point, you've got a data example here and so you have a concrete  opportunity to show precisely what the OP could get.

Comment: Having a csv file would facilitate that, if the OP will provide

Comment: I was going to show a couple of graphs, but I didn't notice until now that the question is closed.

Comment: I just added a vote to reopen.  The question is actually pretty clear and none of us answered the OP's question about whether multiple intercepts are a bother in ordinal regression.  I'd like to take the challenge and analyze the OP's dataset with ordinal regression.  I created a `csv` file.

Comment: @user190134 I just noticed that the ID variable values start over and the for a given ID the sex doesn't change.  So I suspect this is a repeated measures problem with only 8 independent experimental units.  How were you planning on handling that?  This could be handled by adding subject-specific intercepts (random effects) but 8 subjects may be pushing things as it's very hard to estimate the variance of the random effects then.

Comment: @FrankHarrell the ID is not important in this case, yes they repeat but the measures are for different areas. So we are treating female-UN as 6 independent values.

Comment: Just to be clear can we assume that each row corresponds to an independent unit, i.e. there is no correlation (e.g. intra-cluster correlation) between response observatiions in rows?

Answer (score 1):

I've developed a case study where the proportional odds ordinal logistic regression model is applied to the dataset.  It may be found [here](https://hbiostat.org/bbr/nonpar.html#sec-nonpar-2way).  This includes motivation for using a semiparametric model, and some advantages of not needing to know how to transform the dependent variable.  At the end, model-estimated means and medians are computed on the original scale.